# What is causing the delay between recordset.update and the form/report getting the information?

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, report, recordset

## Short version

I'm entering information in a database and fetching it shortly after, but for some reason, when I enter the information, it isn't immediately entered, so that when I try to fetch it, I get old results. Why does this happen? I thought the operations were synchronous.

## Long version

I have a split Access database. At the moment the backend is on my own hard drive to speed up testing, eventually this backend will land on a server. Back when it was a combined frontend/backend database and before I had done a major code refactor (tbh, it was quite the clusterfornication before that), and now this is happening in a number of different scenarios, but pretty much every time I enter information and try to fetch it right after that. Why this happens is a mystery to me, since everything I was reading told me there is no multi-threading in VBA and that everything is synchronous if not specified otherwise, and I haven't enabled any asynchronous options.

Two Examples:

1. I add a record to the database then refresh the form that contains those new records. I'm not going to post the full code (unless it is deemed necessary), since I've modularized the code a lot. But essentially it boils down to this: the user clicks a button which executes this:

```
Private Sub Anhang_hinzufügen_Click()
    If IsNull(Me.Parent.ID) Then
        MsgBox "Bitte erst Felder ausfüllen, und anschließend Anhänge hinzufügen", vbInformation
    Else
        AnhängeAuswählen Me.Parent.Name, Me.Parent.ID
        Me.Form.Requery
    End If
End Sub
```

As part of the `AnhängeAuswählen` method, the method `AddRecord` is called:

```
Function AddRecord(TableName As String, fields() As String, values) As Long
    Dim Table As DAO.Recordset
    Set Table = LUKSVDB.OpenRecordset(TableName)
    Table.AddNew
    For i = LBound(fields) To UBound(fields)
        If TypeName(Table.fields(fields(i)).Value) = "Recordset2" Then
            Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset2
            Set rs2 = Table.fields(fields(i)).Value
            If IsArray(values(i)) Then
                For j = LBound(values(i)) To UBound(values(i))
                    rs2.AddNew
                    rs2!Value = values(i)(j)
                    rs2.Update
                Next j
            Else
                rs2.AddNew
                rs2!Value = values(i)
                rs2.Update
            End If
        Else
            Table.fields(fields(i)) = values(i)
        End If
    Next i
    AddRecord = Table!ID
    Table.Update
    Table.Close
End Function
```

The record is created, that's not the problem. But when it executes `Me.Form.Requery`, the new record doesn't appear in the form. Only when I execute `Me.Form.Requery` a fraction of a second later does the record appear.

2. I add a record to the database using a form, update some information in the recordset with VBA, then requery the subreport with the records. The record appears immediately, but the details I added programmatically only appear when I execute `Me.Parent.Requery` a couple of seconds later.

The first form is a data entry form, so that as soon as the data is saved, it's blank in order to create a new record. The previous should then appear in the form. The button to create the new record looks like this:

```
Private Sub Anmerkung_Hinzufügen_Click()
    currentID = Me.ID
    mSaved = True
    If Me.Dirty Then Me.Dirty = False
    UpdateRecord "Anmerkungen", currentID, StringArray("Person", "Datum"), Array(User, Now)
    Me.Parent.Requery
End Sub
```

The `UpdateRecord` is similar to the `AddRecord` method:

```
Function UpdateRecord(TableName As String, ByVal ID As Integer, fields() As String, values)
    Dim Table As DAO.Recordset
    Set Table = SeekPK(TableName, ID, True)
    Table.Edit
    For i = LBound(fields) To UBound(fields)
        If TypeName(Table.fields(fields(i)).Value) = "Recordset2" Then
            Dim subtable As DAO.Recordset2
            Set subtable = Table.fields(fields(i)).Value
            If IsArray(values(i)) Then
                On Error Resume Next
                Dim t
                t = LBound(values(i))
                If Developer Then On Error GoTo -1 Else On Error GoTo Fehler
                If Err.Number = 0 Then
                    For j = LBound(values(i)) To UBound(values(i))
                        subtable.AddNew
                        subtable!Value = values(i)(j)
                        subtable.Update
                    Next j
                End If
            Else
                subtable.AddNew
                subtable!Value = values(i)
                subtable.Update
            End If
        Else
            Table.fields(fields(i)) = values(i)
        End If
    Next i
    Table.Update
    Table.Close
End Function
```

**Does anyone know why this happens, and how I can prevent it?** I could do a bit of a workaround with timers on the forms, so that it refreshes the form a couple of seconds later, but that seems like a kludgy workaround to me, especially considering I don't know how long it specifically takes, and the times could change drastically once the backend is on the server.

## Additional information, in case it's necessary:

In the code I've posted I've removed some additional code for error handling and performance logging, but it doesn't have any impact on what's happening otherwise.

When the database is opened, a global variable `LUKSVDB As DAO.Database` is initialized:

```
Function ConnectDatabase(Backend As Integer)
    Select Case Backend
        Case 0: DatenOrt = 'redacted, folder in which the production/beta database is located on the server
        Case 1: DatenOrt = 'redacted, folder in which I have a personal testing database on the server
        Case 2: DatenOrt = 'redacted, folder in which I have the testing database on my own computer
    End Select
    Set LUKSVDB = OpenDatabase(DatenOrt & "\LUKS-Verwaltung_be.accdb", False, False, ";pwd=PASSWORD")
End Function
```

For testing purposes, `ConnectDatabase` is launched with a value of 2. However, if it's a problem on my own SSD, where latency is just about 0, then I can only assume it will be a problem on the server as well, where the latency is definitely not 0.

Comment: Sorry, I have never experienced this with server or personal PC db. I will note that `Form` is not needed in the Requery command. You are using UNBOUND forms for data enter/edit? Why are you using Recordset2 - you have multi-value fields? Why? I advise not to use them - I NEVER have nor will.

Comment: I was always wondering if `Form` was necessary, now I know. Funny thing, that actually fixes the problem on the form. Weird. As to your other two questions: 1. The forms are bound. I just need to modify information in those records. The one example is an attachment form (to avoid blowing up the database with attachments), where the user can choose one or multiple attachments, and then my VBA code compresses and uploads the file, gets the size, icon, time uploaded, etc. and uses that to create a new record.

Comment: As to the second question: I've read all over about the problems with multi-value fields, but they were necessary in my case (for keywords, for instance, where a user needs a drop-down list where they can check all applicable keywords). In these examples, they aren't being used though. The `UpdateRecord` and `AddRecord` commands are generic commands, and in the above examples, I'm not passing any multi-value fields, so everything dealing with that is just skipped.